# Issues by upgrading to Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android-studio

I try to update Studio this is what i got. The upgrade ends here for me.[image: Android Studio 2.0 Patch Error Message]

Comment: Which version are you updating from? Ideally since there are a lot of changes, it might be best to download a fresh copy and install it.

Comment: I used only the stable releases so i came from 1.5. I migrated now my settings with a fresh install of studio.
I think the issue is from the patch mechanism. I couldn't found the mentioned path structures in my home folder, so i guess that conflicts somewhere in a merged patch environment.